# DriverManager.getConnection never been executen in my maven project

Tags: java, maven, driver

I tried to understand why my programs never executes this line:

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

Even though I have passed the right values and also all the required dependencies.

```
package com.mtel;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {


    final static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    final static String user = "root";
    final static String pass = "123";



 @POST

    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)

    public String login(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password){
        String result="ok";


        try
        {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Select * From users where username=? and password=?");

            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                result="you' re in";

            }


            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? What exception are you getting?

Comment: i noticed that catches an exception but i don't know what. the output of the program is "build success"

Comment: okay, looking again, its in a try/catch block. remove the try/catch so your exception comes through, loudly. Or figure out where e gets printed in the StackTrace

Comment: i figured it out with multiple "result". and it goes in catch(Exception e)